# Android WebView Issue - Trigger.io

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, trigger.io, tapjoy

I am working on Tapjoy module for trigger.io. I am trying to show the Offerwall using following method -

```
super.loadUrl(url);
```

Now the Problem is that following code works and execute properly when using Android 4.4. But the HTML content doesn't get rendered when using Android 4.3 or below. This is what I get -

[Image Here](http://imagebin.org/302406)

Comment: Does it require html 5? If that's the case you might try different web view libraries that support html 5.

Comment: How can I do that? Currently I am extending the Android WebView class.

Comment: There are open source external libraries that can show you html5 contents. You can find them on github or code google. Since it works in 4.4, probably Chromium Webview released in KitKat is showing your html5 content. But as i said earlier, first you need to confirm if your content is for html5.

Comment: [Please see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719919/tapjoy-offers-wall-not-working-android) - Since the actual code is in tapjoy jar sdk, I cannot change it.